# How to edit slides based on slide_id Python pptx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

**Problem**
I have been looking for a solution but can't find enough documentation to figure it out. I am trying to edit a slide that I had copied into a directory. *(I have make sure to clean out all the data only leaving behind some logo)* What I did is I have printed out the slide ID and tried to access the slide by their ID and hopefully add some textbox for starters. However, I kept getting

```
File "masterScript_2.2.py", line 7385, in <module>
title.text = "Hello, World!"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

**Question**
Is there any solution for it? Thanks and greatly appreciated.

**Code**

```
pptxDst = os.getcwd() + "/" + "test.pptx"
# Load the powerpoint in the respective month folder
prs = Presentation(pptxDst)


for slide in prs.slides:
    print(slide.slide_id)

# Get the slide by id to access it
slide_1 = prs.slides.get(256)
print(slide_1)
title = slide_1.shapes.title

title.text = "Hello, World!"
prs.save("test.pptx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have accessed the slide just fine but the slide does not have a title placeholder.

`Shapes.title` returns the title placeholder if there is one, or `None` if the slide has no title. If you removed all shapes except for a logo, there wouldn't be a title placeholder to find.

This would make the offending line equivalent to:

```
None.text = "Hello, World!"
```

Which explains your error message `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: Actually, when I read the docs, the slide mention that slide layout is a must to operate on the slides ? is it true?

Comment: A slide-layout is required to _add_ a slide. The slide layout is not required to _edit_ a slide though. The slide already knows which layout it was created from.